# NSwag: Generation of a C# client results in invalid code

Tags: c#, .net-core, trello, openapi-generator, nswag

I am trying to generate a `C#` client for the Trello API. Therefore I have downloaded the Open API specification from https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/swagger.v3.json and run the following `nswag` command from the bash.

```sh
nswag openapi2csclient /input:swagger.v3.json \
    /classname:TrelloClient \
    /namespace:Integrations.Trello \
    /output:TrelloClient.cs \
    /GenerateClientInterfaces:True \
    /GenerateExceptionClasses:True \
    /GenerateClientClasses:True \
    /DisposeHttpClient:False \
    /OperationGenerationMode:SingleClientFromOperationId
```

The code generation completes without errors, but the generated code does not compile because it contains many errors. For example, some of the generated method names contain invalid expressions like `=idAsync`, or method signatures have ambiguous parameters (for instance, multiple `key` and `token` parameters of type `string`). The following method declaration has been generated for the `GetMembers` method, which is obviously the wrong syntax.

```cs
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Member> GetMembers=idAsync(
    string key, string token, string id, string actions, string boards, BoardBackgrounds? boardBackgrounds, 
    BoardsInvited? boardsInvited, BoardFields? boardsInvited_fields, bool? boardStars, string cards, 
    CustomBoardBackgrounds? customBoardBackgrounds, CustomEmoji2? customEmoji, CustomStickers? customStickers, 
    MemberFields? fields, string notifications, Organizations? organizations, 
    OrganizationFields? organization_fields, bool? organization_paid_account, 
    OrganizationsInvited? organizationsInvited, OrganizationFields? organizationsInvited_fields, 
    bool? paid_account, bool? savedSearches, Tokens? tokens);
```

Are there any special options that need to be set when processing an Open API specification document of version 3?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve syntax issues regarding the `get-members` method in the generated code by changing the `OperationGenerationMode` from `SingleClientFromOperationId` to `SingleClientFromPathSegments`. This works as a workaround because the `=id` term only appears in the `operationId`.

I inspected Trello´s Open API specification document and found out that the definition of `get-members` contained the `=id` term in the `operationId`; not sure if this is wrong in the spec, or the generator is not able to handle that case correctly. The definition of the `get-members` method looks like that (foreshortened):

```json
... "/members/{id}":
{
   "get":
   {
       "tags": [],
       "operationId":"get-members=id",
       "parameters" ...
   }
}
```

As a sidenote, the reason why I use the `SingleClient...` operation modes is that `Nswag` also adds `GeneratedCode` attributes to any partial class and interface which also results in invalid code (this attribute can only be applied once). The `SingleClient...` operation mode solves that.

What remains is the problem that `NSwag` generates methods with duplicated parameters, which has been reported as an issue, but is not solved yet; see https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/2560 for further information. Last but not least, I tried to remove the `=id` from the `operationId` and switched back to the `SingleClientFromOperationId` operation mode to check whether this does the trick, which is not the case.

I assume that `NSwag` is used by a broad audience which makes me think that this must be more related to the processed spec than `Nswag`. Thus, I looked up the spec for methods that have been reported by the C# compiler to have duplicated parameters. Here is an example.

```json
...
{
    "name": "token",
    "in": "query",
    "description": "The API token to use",
    "required": true,
    "schema": {
        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/APIToken"
    }
},
{
    "name": "token",
    "in": "path",
    "description": "",
    "required": true,
    "schema": {
        "type": "string"
    }
}
...
```

So it seems that a method can have parameters of the same name, but they can appear in different places such a the query-string, or be part of the URL path. Then, it might be `Nswag` that produces the wrong output; if it is intended that both parameters can be sent to the API, then the generator should just prefix the names to avoid ambiguities, for instance, `queryToken` and `pathToken`, leaving it up to the developer to decide what parameter to use or to give a hint to the expected value (in case both parameters are required and expect different values).